# Insertion sort Proof by Induction

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, sorting, correctness-proof, induction

I am reading Algorithm design manual by Skiena. It gives proof of Insertion sort by Induction. I am giving the proof described in the below.

> Consider the correctness of insertion sort, which we introduced at the beginning of this chapter. The reason it is correct can be shown inductively:
>
> 1. The basis case consists of a single element, and by definition a
>    one-element array is completely sorted.
> 2. In general, we can assume that the first n − 1 elements of array A
>    are completely sorted after n − 1 iterations of insertion sort.
> 3. To insert one last element x to A, we find where it goes, namely the
>    unique spot between the biggest element less than or equal to x and
>    the smallest element greater than x. This is done by moving all the
>    greater elements back by one position, creating room for x in the
>    desired location.

I do not understand paragraph #3. Could someone please explain it to me with an example?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/Insertion-sort-example-300px.gif) animation on [Wikipedia's page on insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) will help you understand the 3rd point and the algorithm.

Comment: one more thing, if you are beginner in Algorithms, then try book by [Dasgupta](http://www.amazon.com/Algorithms-Sanjoy-Dasgupta/dp/0073523402) or [CLRS](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844).

Comment: Looking at the proof without the algorithm (in exactly the same version the author uses) does not make much sense.